# Adding a github fork as a dependency on heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github, parse-server

I'm trying to deploy a fork of `parse-server` to a heroku app, but I keep getting a `Error: Cannot find module 'parse-server'` message. I've included the url of my forked repository in the package.json file's dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.11.x",
    "kerberos": "~0.0.x",
    "parse": "~1.8.0",
    "parse-server": "git://github.com/amrkafina/parse-server.git",
}
```

Building works fine:

```
Build succeeded!
├── express@4.11.2
├── kerberos@0.0.22
├── parse@1.8.5
├── parse-server@2.2.25-beta.1 (git://github.com/amrkafina/parse-server.git#91c334900b5a75c7d7a8ba7de7e7b418eb54779c)
```

But I keep getting the error when running the server:

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-11-19T06:25:23.864321+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'parse-server'
```

I've tried changing the dependency's URL (https, user/projectname, tarball archives) but it's always the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try adding the "#master" ... https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Comment: @RobertRowntree I tried, but it still didn't work. My fork is 1 commit ahead of the origin's master branch. Would that cause the problem?

Comment: i would start at beginning.. clone it to new project .... npm install ..... build ..... run

Comment: @RobertRowntree Already tried doing that - nothing. :(

Comment: That won't work as only the src folder is committed and the lib folder is only included through NPM. if you want your fork to work, you should update the package.json to include the `src` folder and run through babel.